# Windows Recovery ISO image

Tags: windows-10, usb, iso-image, system-restore

My windows 10 installation has broken and won't get past boot sequence. I want to try and do a system restore.
I could download the ISO from microsoft and load onto a usb but I don't have a usb drive that's big enough for the 4.4GB it needs.

I'm pretty sure I had system restore making backups before the thing broke. 
Is there a smaller recovery ISO that I can get my hands on? I don't think I need ALL the win10 system files to do system restore do I?

Comment: The simplest answer is to buy a drive that's big enough: they aren't expensive, and you are going to need one sooner or later. Otherwise, you'll spend a great deal of time and effort trying to avoid a trivial expenditure. I would suggest at least 16GB: you never know how big Windows is going to get. They are priced from under £6 in UK.

Comment: They sell 8GB USB storage devices for under $10. You can also create a bootable optical disk for under $0.50 provided you have a drive and a blank disk

Answer (score 2):

The minimum size of 1709 iso for 64-bit is 4.42GB, Enterprise edition is even bigger.

32-bit iso is 3.31 GB, but I don’t recommend to use it if your RAM is bigger than 2GB.

Just buy a 8 GB USB drive to create your bootable installation drive.